# How do you manually add linetype legend in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that has two types of lines, but I cant get it to show up in the legend like the colours do. My datasets look like

```
Role <- LETTERS[1:3]
df1 <- data.frame (totalFemByLevel = c(104,23,9),
                   totalMalByLevel = c(48,30,12),
                   Role)
df2 <- data.frame (totalFemByLevel = c(100,30,6),
                   totalMalByLevel = c(44,25,10),
                   Role)
```

With one being from 2016 and the other being from 2019, both structured the same.

```
CompareTotalPlot <- function(df1, df2, title) {   Plot <- ggplot(data
= df1, aes(x = factor(Role), group = 1))+  #female=red, male = steelblue
    geom_line(aes(y=totalFemByLevel, col = "red"), size = 1.5) +
    geom_point(aes(y=totalFemByLevel, col = "red"), size = 7)+
    geom_text(aes(y=totalFemByLevel, label = totalFemByLevel))+
    
    geom_line(aes(y=totalMalByLevel, col ="steelblue"), size = 1.5) +
    geom_point (aes(y=totalMalByLevel,col = "steelblue"), size = 7)+
    geom_text(aes(y=totalMalByLevel, label = totalMalByLevel))+
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "Year",
                          values = c(1,2), 
                          labels = c("2019", "2016"))+ #l
    scale_colour_manual(name = "Gender",
                        labels = c("Women","Men"),
                        values = c("red","steelblue"))+
    labs(x= "Level",
         y= "Total",
         title = title
    )
    
     Plot <- Plot+geom_line(data=df2, aes(y=totalFemByLevel, col = "red"), size = 1, linetype = 2)+
       geom_line(data=df2, aes(y=totalMalByLevel, col = "steelblue"), size = 1, linetype = 2 )
    
        }
```

[image: plot]

This is the plot my current code outputs, Im happy with everything except for the legend.

Comment: Try modifying your geom_line themes adding `geom_line(...,show.legend = T)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't got anything mapped to the linetype aesthetic, so even if you could have a legend, you wouldn't have different line types on your plot.

Typically it's best if you're wanting to map aesthetics to variables for the purposes of creating a legend, it's best to do this by creating a single "long format" data frame. Here's a fully reproducible example (I have used your plot to recover the approximate data points rather than the example data frames):

```r
df1  <- data.frame(totalFemByLevel = c(56, 51, 16, 8, 6),
                   totalMalByLevel = c(59, 49, 21, 15, 23),
                   Role = LETTERS[1:5])

df2  <- data.frame(totalFemByLevel = c(62, 43, 14, 4, 1),
                   totalMalByLevel = c(56, 35, 34, 7, 18),
                   Role = LETTERS[1:5])

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df2, df1) %>%
  mutate(Year = factor(c(rep(2019, 5), rep(2016, 5)))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c("totalFemByLevel", "totalMalByLevel")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Role, y = value, color = name, group = paste(Year, name))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Year, size = Year)) +
  geom_point(size = 7, aes(alpha = Year)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, alpha = Year), colour = "black") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 2)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1.5, 0.75)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0), guide = guide_none()) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Gender",
                      labels = c("Women", "Men"),
                      values = c("red", "steelblue")) +
  labs(x= "Level", y= "Total", title = "2016/2019 Comparison")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Sorry shouldve explained it more clearly but I have two dataframes, one with totals of employees, their gender and what level they are employed at from 2019, and another dataframe with the same data just from 2016. I dont have a variable called year, its just the label I want in the legend.

Im just surprised that you need to create the legend with it extracting data from the plot instead of being able to manually just do whatever you want.

Comment: @Adam that's why it's a good idea to add example data to your question - otherwise people have to guess, and it doubles the work involved fixing a problem. The legends in ggplot are designed to "just work" without having to specify them every time. You just tell it which variable you want associated with which aesthetic, and it will change the plot and create the legend automatically. You can still do it with data in your format, but it's much better to have your data in a single long-format data frame - a "tidy" format. You can edit your question to show sample data - or I could gues again?

Comment: No need to guess, hopefully, that data I added helps.